# In sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select  tblProductMaster.*,AVG(tblReviewMaster.Rating) from tblProductMaster 
    left join tblReviewMaster 
    on tblProductMaster.ProductID = tblReviewMaster.ProductID       
Group By tblProductMaster.ProductID
```

This query is returning an error:

> *Column 'tblReviewMaster.ReviewID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.*

It is not allowing me to have any column with AVG function... if I write

```
select AVG(tblReviewMaster.Rating) from tblProductMaster ...
```

then it works fine

So what to do to get product details from `tblProductMaster` also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message says "Column 'tblReviewMaster.ReviewID' is invalid in the select list because **it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**"

This means all the columns other than column in aggregate functions(AVG) should be a part of Group By Clause. So if * means (Column 1, Column 2....etc) so all of these columns must be present in GroupBy clause.

So your query would be

```
select  tblProductMaster.*,AVG(tblReviewMaster.Rating) from tblProductMaster 
    left join tblReviewMaster 
    on tblProductMaster.ProductID = tblReviewMaster.ProductID       
Group By tblProductMaster.*
```

By *, I mean write all columns that represent *. * won't work here.

Please find more details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: thanks for reply and it is working fine.. u saved my much time.. :)

Comment: @shivanipatel: It is always recommended on Stackoverflow to accept the answer if it was useful and is a best answer for your question. This helps others looking for solution.